# Annotate Javascript Class Constructor with JSDoc Custom Type

Tags: javascript, types, jsdoc

I defined a custom type in JSDoc like this:

```
/**
  * @typedef {{
  *   myProperty: number
  * }} MyType
  */
```

Now I annotate a class with it like this:

```
/**
  * @constructor
  * @extends {MyType}
  */
function MyClass() {
    this.myProperty = 123;
}
```

However, when I try to assign an instance of the class to a variable I annotated with the type, my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) gives me an error: "Initializer type `MyClass` is not assignable to variable type `MyType`".

```
/** @type {MyType} */
let myInstance = new MyClass();
```

I suspect that "initializer types" work somehow differently but I couldn't figure out how. I also tried to use `@augments` or `@implements` annotations but it didn't help.